# ios - Swift - dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier, Cells of collectionViewController (in UIView) won't load after scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a ViewController with 3 views :

- Header (UIView)
- TabBar (UIView)
- UIView3 (UIView)

In my UIView3 I have a collectionViewController. A key element is that I put my **collectionViewController.scrollEnable = False** because otherwhise, when I'm scrolling, only the UIView3 is scrolling and I want my entier screen to scroll (so that if we scroll enough my Header and Tabbar are hidden.

So this is what I have :

[image]

And this is how my screen looks like :

[image]

Which is perfect. **But**, when I'm scrolling down, this is what it **should** looks like :

[image]

**But instead**, it looks like this :

[image]

I think my problem comes from the "dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier" function which doesn't see that I'm scrolling but I have no idea how to "refresh" the scroll value so it loads the end of cells 3-4 and also the cells 5-6.

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Can you paste some code??

Comment: @TapasPal Which part do you want ? My code is pretty large but I know that everything works separately. The UICollectionView controller works perfectly when its not in a UIView.

Comment: Your problem is not in dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier. Height of  UIView3 or collection view is wrong. Try adding a different color border to both of them (.layer.border* - quartz core) so you see their bounds when you scroll up.

Comment: Also, your approach seems too convoluted. Why not use a simple collection view controller and make a large custom section header view with your view1 and tab bar?

Comment: @lukya Well, the UiView3 height looks fine and the collectionView controller also because, even though it doen't load the collectionView, the UIView3 update its height exactly the height it should have (so I can scroll a white screen the same size it should have if the collectionView was loading) and I do UIView3.height = UIcollectionView.contentSize.height so I think this is not the problem

Comment: @lukya Because I tried before with a custom section header view but it didn't work the way I wanted

Comment: Not just the contentSize, you do also update Collection View's height along with UIView 3 right?

Comment: @lukya That solved my problem ! I was only updating my collectionView contentSize and not my contentViewHeight... You are a genius ! <3 Now, I have only one more problem, all the cells that are not shown before the scroll cannot be selectable (but the others (the first two) are)...